# PHP header location redirecting to real port instead of fake one

Tags: php, nginx

I have a running nginx web server using PHP 7.4 (FPM) using Ubuntu 20.04. The web server runs on port 2080 and 2443, and they are port forwarded on port 2443 LAN 443 WAN.

I have a PHP script that should redirect me to another page of my website, but it redirects me on a page that uses port 2443 which is inaccesible since i need 443. I tried all possible things but it won't work and it will still redirect me to port 2443.
Note that i cannot use port 443 locally on my nginx server, so that isn't a option.

I have tried:

```
header('Location: https://domain.tld:443/page');
header('Location: https://domain.tld/page');
header('Location: https://domain.tld./page');
```

however with no success as it's redirecting me on https://domain.tld:2443/page .

So how do i fix this?

Comment: Why the odd port assignment

Comment: Redirects are processed by the browser. This should go to the public port 443, which will be forwarded to 2443. If the router performs port forwarding, there's no way to bypass it.

Comment: PHP would not do this. The likely culprit is the proxy rewriting the response.

Comment: There's no proxy except of the router... i don't think the router would interfere with http requests

Comment: The proxy here is nginx itself. Add your nginx config to your question.

Comment: Even with the default nginx config with php enabled, but still the same. Only thing that's changed are the "listen" variables which are set to port 2443 and 2080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was that it redirected to "page/".

I changed this:
`header('Location: https://domain.tld/page');`

to this:
`header('Location: https://domain.tld/page/');`

And now it does no longer redirect to a :2443 port.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a relative url

```
header('Location: ./page'); // assuming your cwd is in the root
```

the server will take care of protocol (HTTP vs HTTPS) and port (it will reuse the one used for the request).

this URL also is relative to your site and retains protocol and port used in the request.

```
header('Location: /page');
```

Comment: I needed ../ for this since the executing script is in another folder , tried it and still the same problem.

Comment: We need a bit more details then. What is the URL you use to reach and execute your PHP script? (redact the server address if needed but keep untouched the other parts of the URL)

Comment: https://domain.tld/script/index.php

Comment: No HTTPS and port? Do you reach a page on port 80/2080 and want to redirect to a different page on a different port (443)?

Comment: Only https, seems like it got filtred by stackoverflow. Port 2443 is used internally and the router is forwarding it to 443 on the external IP (a.k.a public one). The 80/2080 ports are kind of out of the subject, but 2080 internally is being forwarded to 80 externally. This (domain.tld/script/index.php who is on port 443 on https) needs to be redirected to domain.tld/page on https on port 443. Instead it redirects on https on port 2443, as a result the page is not working and is returning a connection timed out error.

Comment: If you do a location to `header('Location: https://domain.tld:443/page/index.php');` does it works?

Comment: No, this is exactly the first thing i tried when i found out about this problem.